# Checking nested object value from firebase realtime db?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my object,

```
 const data = {
   7Wkdijxaa001: {
        2bMjRYcaJL4tMxr1k8vE:{
             amount: 750,
             date: 1617120845312,
             startDate: "March 31,2021",
             status: "cancelled"
       },
       DSEnhMvi2lc4OL9bnUsw:{
             amount: 50,
             date: 1617371574679,
             startDate: ""April 30,2021"",
             status: "cancelled"
       },
  },
  Dkiah11mmjcjnajk: {
        zc9vUzYlqM3DxEW6tk86:{
             amount: 750,
             date: 1617120845312,
             startDate: "March 31,2021",
             status: "cancelled"
       },
       DSEnhMvi2lc4OL9bnUsw:{
             ....
             .....
             .......
       },
  }
}
```

Actually, this is list of orders placed by users and i have a 20k of records of this on realtime database . Now i need to read startDate and filter the data's to show under "Today's order" at admin panel. For ex- if todays date is March 31, i need to go over all the 20k records and get the object which has start date of March 31 and display that on admin panel ?

How to do this, I can successfully fetch all the data's but could understand these nested objects. Am using and trying with lodash

How to perform this please guide, i tried mapping - So how to filter based on the nested objects key ? In this case i need to filter based on "startDate"

```
_.map(data)
```

But i dont feel its right method, am a total newbie please help !

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if there is a direct way to do so as there is a wildcard (the user UID) involved in path. Firestore would have been more ideal for this use case. However you can fetch all the orders and then filter the data on the frontend:

```
const data = {
    "7Wkdijxaa001": {
        "2bMjRYcaJL4tMxr1k8vE": {
            amount: 750,
            date: 1617120845312,
            startDate: "March 31,2021",
            status: "cancelled"
        },
        "DSEnhMvi2lc4OL9bnUsw": {
            amount: 50,
            date: 1617371574679,
            startDate: "April 30,2021",
            status: "cancelled"
        },
    },
    "Dkiah11mmjcjnajk": {
        "zc9vUzYlqM3DxEW6tk86": {
            amount: 750,
            date: 1617120845312,
            startDate: "March 31,2021",
            status: "cancelled"
        }
    }
}

const today = "March 31,2021"
const todaysOrders = []

Object.entries(data).forEach((user) => {
    Object.entries(data[user[0]]).forEach((order) => {
        if (order[1]["startDate"] === today) {
            todaysOrders.push({orderId: order[0], ...order[1]})
        }
    })
})


console.log(todaysOrders);
```

I ran the code on your sample JSON and here's the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, will check on this !

Comment: @christine11sure. If that works you can accept the answer by clicking tick icon so others know the issue is resolved else feel free to answer further questions.

Comment: is this an effective way ? How it will perform under thousands of records ?

Comment: @christine11 nope, I would recommend moving on to Firestore or changing the structure here. In Firestore the queries would be easier.

Comment: But wont that be costly comparing Realtime db ?

Comment: @christine11 actually that depends. If you are storing all those records for long term the Firestore is cheaper for storage. You pay for each read and write in Firestore while in realtime db for bandwidth. The best you maybe able to do in rtdb is but all the orders in single node and not divide them under user UIDs so you maybe able to use `.equalTo()` method to find orders with specific date.

Comment: If thats the case, how shall we query a particular users order ?